# Get the number of Items in a List

Tags: list, flutter, dart

Is there a way in dart to count and get the number of items in a List? So, when you have a list with five words in it, it would output you the number five, when the method is called?

Comment: Use list.length to get the number list items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

list_variable_name.length

[Reference: Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_list_length_method.htm)

Comment: Note that Dart lists are not naturally length-constrained, as arrays in some languages can be. Lists grow and shrink as needed through the use of the add and remove methods.
"Flutter for Beginners" by Thomas Bailey, Alessandro Biessek.

Answer (score 1):

You just take your list variable and do .length on it to return how long it is.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/List-class.html